# Adjust words position with stopword filter

Tags: elasticsearch

The stopword filter of Elasticsearch maintains words position : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/using-stopwords.html#maintaining-positions

For example here is my analyzer:

```
"myAnalyzer": {
    "tokenizer": "standard",
    "filter": ["asciifolding", "french_elision", "lowercase", "french_stop", "french_stemmer"]
}
```

And here the analyze of my string :

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_analyze?pretty=true' -d '{"analyzer": "myAnalyzer", "text": "instruments de musique"}'
Index 339 documents...
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "instrument",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 11,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 0
  }, {
    "token" : "musiqu",
    "start_offset" : 15,
    "end_offset" : 22,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 2
  } ]
}
```

Is there a way to adjust positions so the word "musique" will be in position 1 instead of 2?

My problem is coming from phase queries.

Comment: If you make instrument a stop word yes, but not sure why you would want to do that?

Comment: Because in a phrase query I want to be able to search "instrument de musique" ("de" is a stopword) or "instrument musique", and it doesn't work because of the position. I don't want to play with the "slop" parameter of phrase query if possible.

Comment: Have you tried removing the stop word filter?

Comment: Also check this out for a more efficient way to do this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/common-grams.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try using query_string with `enable_position_increments:false`
Something like

```
{  "query_string":{
    "default_field":"text",
    "query":"\"instruments de musique\"",
    "enable_position_increments":false
  }
}
```

Comment: For anyone stumbling on this, this solution only applies to the query, not the indexed content, so it does not address the problem.